# Google VR cardboard on Android. App not shown in launcher, only cardboard app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I have built an app in Unity. So far, the Android build has appeared in the Android device launcher. After some updates to SDK/code, the app only appears in the cardboard app; the app is invisible in device launcher. I have looked at the Android Manifest, and both the Launcher and cardboard is included in the intent filter as follows:

```
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD" />
      </intent-filter>
```

Any ideas to fix issue, so that app appears in launcher?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be the latest Oculus SDK- which is included in the app to support Oculus. Before, it did not cause an issue on Mobile- now it does.